# display age groups in chart in mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, charts, bar-chart

I'm trying to calculate age groups in my database and display them on a chart.

I've got this code below to display for drugs Category and quantity on a bar chart.

```
public JsonResult DrugStatus()
    {
        List<Drug> drg = new List<Drug>();
        DataContext da = new DataContext();
        drg = da.Drugs.ToList();

        var chartData = new object[drg.Count + 1];
        chartData[0] = new object[]{
            "Drug Group",
            "Drug Quantity"
        };

        int count = 0;
        foreach (var i in drg)
        {
            count++;
            chartData[count] = new object[] { i.DrugCategory, i.Quantity };
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = chartData, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
    }
```

I want to do the same for the different age groups of customers in my DB but I'm having problems in the logic.

Below is what I've done

```
public JsonResult AgeGroup()
    {
        List<Patient> patient = new List<Patient>();
        DataContext da = new DataContext();

        patient = da.Patients.ToList();

        var select = (from a in da.Patients
                      group a by a.Age into g
                      select new
                      {
                          Age = g.Key,
                          Age1 = g.Where(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Age) >= 13 && Convert.ToInt32(a.Age) <= 18).Count()
                      });
        var chartData = new object[patient.Count + 1];
        chartData[0] = new object[]{
            "Age Group"
        };

        string age1, age2, age3, age4, age5;
        foreach (Patient p in da.Patients)
        {
            int Age = Convert.ToInt32(p.Age);

            if ((Age >= 13) && (Age <= 18))
            {
                age1 = "13 - 18";
            }

            if ((Age >= 19) && (Age <= 30))
            {
                age2 = "19 - 30";
            }

            if ((Age >= 31) && (Age <= 45))
            {
                age3 = "31 - 45";
            }

            if ((Age >= 46) && (Age <= 60))
            {
                age4 = "46 - 60";
            }

            if (Age >= 61)
            {
                age5 = "61 Above";
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to add it to a list so I can loop it like i did in the DrugStatus()

```
foreach (var i in drg)
    {
        count++;
        chartData[count] = new object[] { i.DrugCategory, i.Quantity };
    }
```

but first I want to add the values to a list how can I go about this logic ...any help ???

Answer (score 0):

Okay after later thinking and much concentration I discovered that I could do the logic and add to a generic list "Class" Which I did by creating a class to store the values as seen below.

```
public class AgeClass
    {
        public string AgeG { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }

        public AgeClass()
        {
            AgeG = "";
            count = 0;
        }

        public AgeClass(string Age, int C)
        {
            AgeG = Age;
            count = C;
        }
    }
```

Afterwards I proceeded with the JsonResult Logic, wrote the logic to get a particular age group and count how many people belong to that particular age group as seen below...

```
public JsonResult AgeGroup()
    {
        List<AgeClass> agc = new List<AgeClass>();

        DataContext da = new DataContext();

        string age1 = "", age2 = "", age3 = "", age4 = "", age5 = "";
        int Count1 = 0, Count2 = 0, Count3 = 0, Count4 = 0, Count5 = 0;

        foreach (Patient p in da.Patients)
        {
            int Age = Convert.ToInt32(p.Age);

            if ((Age >= 13) && (Age <= 18))
            {
                age1 = "13 - 18";
                Count1++;
            }

            if ((Age >= 19) && (Age <= 30))
            {
                age2 = "19 - 30";
                Count2++;
            }

            if ((Age >= 31) && (Age <= 45))
            {
                age3 = "31 - 45";
                Count3++;
            }

            if ((Age >= 46) && (Age <= 60))
            {
                age4 = "46 - 60";
                Count4++;
            }

            if (Age >= 61)
            {
                age5 = "61 Above";
                Count5++;
            }
        }
```

after getting all that I proceeded to adding the results to the AgeClass I created earlier.

```
 AgeClass obj1 = new AgeClass(age1, Count1);
        AgeClass obj2 = new AgeClass(age2, Count2);
        AgeClass obj3 = new AgeClass(age3, Count3);
        AgeClass obj4 = new AgeClass(age4, Count4);
        AgeClass obj5 = new AgeClass(age5, Count5);

        agc.Add(obj1);
        agc.Add(obj2);
        agc.Add(obj3);
        agc.Add(obj4);
        agc.Add(obj5);
```

then created the chartData and inserted the values into it and looped through the AgeClass which already holds the data of my age groups..

```
var chartData = new object[agc.Count + 1];
        chartData[0] = new object[]{
            "Age Group",
            "Age Count"
        };

        int count = 0;
        foreach (var i in agc)
        {
            count++;
            chartData[count] = new object[] { i.AgeG, i.count };
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = chartData, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

And displayed it in my bar chart view and it works fine, I hope this helps someone.

**And props to Carly Rae Jepsen "Emotions" album which i had on repeat and also Chocolate City "The Indestructible Choc Boi Nation" album music helps programmers think lol !**

***Any other way of coming up with this solution will be much appreciated...Thanks***